# Saving preference after handling positive in dialog

Tags: android

I have an `EditTextPreference` that I would like to validate. This means I would have to prevent the dialog from closing if the validation fails. I set my own click listener, but the preference isn't being saved when dismissing the dialog - probably because the click is no longer being handled from the dialog builder:

```
public class CustomDialog extends EditTextPreference {

    public CustomDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(final Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Dismiss
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);
    }
}
```

Do I just have to commit the preference manually?

**EDIT:** Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:title="android custom prefs test">
    <com.nerth.vixin.CustomDialog android:defaultValue="@string/address" android:title="IP Address" android:key="key_1"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Setting the custom layout to the dialog resolves the problem of auto dismiss.

Comment: @SanjeetAjnabee I'm not quite sure I understand. If you could provide some more detail, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: in your onClick(), before dismiss(), you need to persist the value yourself. There are various methods (persistString(), etc) you can call to do it for you.

Comment: @kha That worked! The only issue now is that text field is displaying the old value. I'm not sure where's it's referencing it from, but shouldn't it be grabbing the current preference value?

Comment: @Raggeth override `onBindDialogView()` (or one of the other overrides that are called before it displays the value) and use the method that gets the persisted value. I don't remember what it is but it's going to be something similar to `getPersistedString()`. There's an attribute you can specify on the xml layout (if you're using one) which is like "isPersisted" that should automatically do all of these for you though but if not, this should do it.

Comment: @kha Yep, all I did was call the `setText` method and pass in the persisted string. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Raggeth No problem. Please add your solution as answer (full working code) and accept as self-answer so that in the future, others having the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Thanks to [kha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3839882/kha) for the tip about `onBindDialogView`:

```
public class CustomDialog extends EditTextPreference {

    public CustomDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(final Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                persistString("Default");
                // Use whatever checks before calling dismiss
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        setText(getPersistedString("Default"));
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder){
 super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder)
 builder.setCancelable(false)
 }
```

Comment: Some kind of explanation would be useful to make this a complete answer.